# How can I cut off the corner of a container without allowing content within to overflow?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

A client has requested that I create an image slider which is quadrilateral but not rectangular. The slider ends half way across a page and mustn't overlap the right side content. An example of this would be:

[image: Example Image]

## First Attempt

I've currently created [**this JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DkCQP/1/) which uses borders to sheer off the bottom right corner. This is in two parts: `#intro-bottom-left` which is the foreground and `#intro-bottom-left-back` which is the background (and what creates the border effect along the right side.

#### HTML

```html
<section id="intro">
    <div id="intro-bottom">
        <div id="intro-bottom-left-back"></div>
        <div id="intro-bottom-left"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```css
#intro-bottom-left {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    border-top: 410px solid white;
    border-right: 153px solid transparent;
    border-left: 211px solid white;
}

#intro-bottom-left-back {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    border-top: 410px solid black;
    border-right: 154px solid transparent;
    border-left: 212px solid black;
}
```

I've made this on a slightly smaller scale to fit easily within the JSFiddle result UI area. This creates:

[image: JSFiddle First Attempt]

*Note how I've given the body a grey background to show how this isn't affected.*

## The Problem

The client has specified that **this must work on IE8**, which rules out using the [CSS3 `border-image` property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) or using [CSS3 2D Transformations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) to add in or modify the images and their containers.

I need to somehow add in an `<img />` element on top of this which is unable to overflow outside of the boundaries of the shape, without covering any of the area to the right. As the `#intro-bottom-left` container has no width or height other than what is created by the borders, simply adding an image in and giving the container `overflow: hidden` will not achieve anything.

#### Given the below markup ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DkCQP/3/)), what can I do to get this image to display the same as the first example at the top without overlapping any of the right content?

```html
<div id="intro-bottom-left">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible (yet).

Comment: @putvande were it not for the IE8 requirement this would be possible using [CSS 2D Transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to `skew` the container then `skew` the content the opposite way to give it an upright effect. These unfortunately are not supported on IE8.

Comment: "The slider ends half way across a page and mustn't overlap the right side content" Do you mean that the triangular white area to the right of the image (in your example) will hold content that must be visible?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes. The page's background with text on top. This is why in the JSFiddle demo I've given the body a `#eee` background to show that this shouldn't have anything on top.

Comment: Then it's basically impossible as stated AFAIK. All HTML elements are rectangular although they sometime don't look like it. You couldn't get text to flow into that triangular 'body' area,

Answer (score 0):

You could use IE filters to achieve the CSS3 2D Transformation effect in IE8. Try this tool:
http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

**Update:** 
The fiddle below looks the same in IE8, Chrome and Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/jjbrn/

You have to adjust the positioning manually through negative margins to compensate for the difference in transform-origin.

```
body {
    background: #444;
}

#intro-bottom {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#intro-bottom-left {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding-left: 90px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);

    /* IE8 */ 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=-0.3639702342662026, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
    margin-left: -182px\0/; 
}

.slide {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);

    /* IE8 */ 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0.3639702342662022, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
    margin-left: -90px\0/;

}
```

Comment: `skew` doesn't appear to work in IE8, even with the `-ms-filter` they've suggested. It's also a little ironic that that page doesn't work at all in IE7.

Comment: You probably have to use skewX instead of skew in that tool. I have updated the answer with a working fiddle and checked it in IE8.